# How to properly wait until ActionListener is executed?

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, awt, actionlistener

I have a simple, variably sized tic-tac-toe App that works differently on different machines. On my laptop it works like I want it to and on my desktop, it gets stuck in the `ButtonListener` class that implements `ActionListener`. I'm pretty sure this is because of the way I am waiting for a action to be performed, using a `while` loop. Here is the offending code snippet.

```
public void playOneTurn(int player) {
    waiting = true;
    while (waiting) {
        // Do nothing, touchEvent will change waiting.
    }
}
```

I meant for this method to simply wait for a valid spot to be selected and for `waiting` to be flipped in the `ButtonListener`:

```
    class ButtonListener implements ActionListener {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        System.out.println("TOUCHEVENT");

        for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
            for (j = 0; j < size; j++)
                if (e.getSource() == cells[i][j]) {
                    if (model[i][j] == 'e') {
                        cells[i][j].setText("");
                        currentSpot[0] = i;
                        currentSpot[1] = j;
                        if (count % 2 == 0) {
                            cells[i][j].setBackground(Color.GREEN);
                            cells[i][j].setIcon(X_MARK);
                            model[i][j] = 'x';
                            count++;
                            waiting = false;
                        } else {
                            cells[i][j].setBackground(Color.CYAN);
                            cells[i][j].setIcon(O_MARK);
                            model[i][j] = 'o';
                            count++;
                            waiting = false;

                        }

                    } else {
                        System.out.println("Hey, you can't move there silly!");
                    }
                }
    }
}
```

I know nothing about threads but I believe that the `ButtonListener` is starting a thread, and because of the way I'm waiting on it, with the `while` loop, the thread is never stopped to let the rest of my code run on certain machines.

Is my error in using the while loop to wait on an Event to flip a boolean, and if so, how would I properly wait for it?

Comment: Launch a separate thread to run `playOneTurn`, and put `Thread.sleep()` into your loop, to save cpu cycles

Comment: The different behavior *might* be caused by the fact that `waiting` is probably not declared as `volatile`: When one thread changes its value, then another thread does not necessarily see the new value (unless the variable is `volatile` or there is a form of synchronization). But as it was already pointed out: What you are doing there is called "busy waiting" and usually a bad practice, and it should be replaced by `synchronized`, `wait()` and `notifyAll()`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do not simply use `while(true)` loop. It will take up your CPU usage. Use `synchronization` instead. Create a `private final Object` and call `wait()` on it. Prior to this send a reference of this object to the MessageListener. When your operation in  MessageListener is completed you can call `notify()` on it.

Also take care of [Spurious wakeups](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spurious_wakeup).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I can't figure out how to add the `synchronization` code properly. First, I don't know if I'm inserting the code in the correct places, secondly I don't know how to handle the InterruptedException, or why it's being thrown. I knew there was something wrong with having a `while` loop constantly looking a boolean.

Answer (score 3):

You should redesign your application. There is no need to wait at all. The entire state of your application will not change unless there is some event (i.e. user input) which triggers such a change. That’s especially true for a tic-tac-toe game. The condition you want to wait for cannot become true unless some user input changed the state in way that allows it. Therefore you can check for the condition inside the listener at places where the condition could have become true. And then react on it immediately.

Therefore you should implement listeners which react on events, change the state of your application and return. The next state transition will happen when the next event occurs, not a single CPU cycle before that. If you want to do changes independent of user generated events, i.e. animations, use a `Timer` which will generate appropriate events.

Comment: This might not be true in case of a computer player that computes the best move in an own thread.

Comment: @Marco13: Besides the fact that `tic tac toe` does not require such a computation: it makes no sense in a turn-based game where each player has to wait for the other before even being able to start thinking about his/her/its own turn. And even in games where such a background computation is possible, i.e. the AI has not to wait for the human’s turn: well, it implies that there is no need to wait for the human’s turn…