# How to stop ActionListener from halting all other code?

Tags: java, swing, awt, actionlistener, synchronized

I asked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21874923/how-to-properly-wait-until-actionlistener-is-executed/21874997#21874997) question yesterday and have attempted to implement the top answer I received. So from the code from yesterday I have tried adding `synchronized` to my methods and using `wait()` and `notifyAll()`. I have been looking up a bunch of examples, and reading the documentation but I'm definitely not doing it right.

Basically, once a touchEvent happens my `ButtonListener` stops all of my other code from executing, and only performs the code contained within the `ButtonListener`. **This only happens on one of my computers though, my laptop runs the code the way I expected it to, my desktop gets stuck in the `ButtonListener`.** This was a school assignment I turned in a couple weeks ago and initially received a 70%, but I explained to my teacher that it works on some computers and he ran it on his office desktop, and viola, it worked and I got a 100%. Of course I want to figure out what the problem is though so that is why I'm still working on this.

Here are the offending code snippets:

```
    public synchronized void playOneTurn(int player)
        throws InterruptedException {
    waiting = true;
    while (waiting) {
        try {
            System.out.println("playOneTurn before wait.");
            wait();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    System.out.println("playOneTurn AFTER wait.");
    }
```

My method here, `playOneTurn`, is the last bit of code that runs before the first touch event. Previously, as you can tell by looking at my question linked at the top, I used a simple `while` loop that waited for my `ButtonListener` to flip a boolean, `waiting`. Above is my attempt to use `synchronized`.

```
    class ButtonListener implements ActionListener {
    @Override
    public synchronized void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        System.out.println("Entering Action Performed");
        for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            for (j = 0; j < size; j++) {
                if (e.getSource() == cells[i][j]) {
                    if (model[i][j] == 'e') {
                        cells[i][j].setText("");
                        currentSpot[0] = i;
                        currentSpot[1] = j;
                        if (count % 2 == 0) {
                            cells[i][j].setBackground(Color.GREEN);
                            cells[i][j].setIcon(X_MARK);
                            model[i][j] = 'x';
                            count++;
                            waiting = false;
                            System.out.println("Boolean hit");
                            notifyAll();
                        } else {
                            cells[i][j].setBackground(Color.CYAN);
                            cells[i][j].setIcon(O_MARK);
                            model[i][j] = 'o';
                            count++;
                            waiting = false;
                            System.out.println("Boolean hit");
                            notifyAll();
                        }

                    } else {
                        System.out
                                .println("Hey, you can't move there silly!");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    }
```

Here is my `ButtonListener` where my program just chills in and stops doing anything else. Please disregard my random `println`s everywhere, I was just getting aggravated and trying to find out what this thing is doing.

I also had to add this try/catch block to my controller class:

```
        while (!game.haveWinner() && !game.isFull()) {
        player = (player + 1) % 2;
        try {
            game.playOneTurn(player);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
             e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("While loop looped");
    }
```

I have been trying every way I can think of to correctly implement `synchronized` but I'm obviously doing something wrong.

[Here is a Dropbox link to the entire program if it would help.](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/6th0fj8fps6wpgi/33jYrKQICV)

Comment: I can't tell what the problem is but I looked at your Dropbox code and I don't think you need two threads here. It seems like you could just call `haveWinner` and `isFull` from the event.

Comment: OK, so instead of having the `while` loop drive the game, I should have the `ActionListener` calling all the methods that steps the game forward? I think that is what @Eels was saying.

Comment: Yes, I think that's what he means by "event-driven" and he is right.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This:

```
while (!game.haveWinner() && !game.isFull()) {
```

Is going to tie up the Swing event thread and freeze your entire application .... don't do it.

Your code looks like you're trying to hack a linear console program into a Swing GUI, and that never works because their program flow and logic are completely different. The solution is to change your logic to more event-driven.

You presumably have a game loop somewhere, perhaps using a Swing Timer ... so check with each iteration of the loop for winner or for is full.

You need to get all waiting, all synchronized, all notifies out of your program. Instead make a button press change it's state.

---

**Edit**
I was playing around with your code, and came up with something like this. Note that synchronization is not my strong suite, so take this with a grain of salt, but my key goal is to make sure that Swing GUI creation code and state changing code is called only on the Swing event thread, and that any other code, especially code that requires synchronization with other threads, is not called on the Swing event thread.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.*;

public class TicTacToeApp {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      TicTacToeGame game;
      int size, need, player = 1;
      String[] names = new String[2];
      Scanner kbd = new Scanner(System.in);

      // TODO: uncomment in running code
      // System.out.print("Enter Player 1's name:  ");
      // names[0] = kbd.nextLine();
      // System.out.print("Enter Player 2's name:  ");
      // names[1] = kbd.nextLine();
      //
      // System.out.print("Enter the TIC-TAC-TOE grid size:  ");
      // size = kbd.nextInt();
      // System.out.print("Enter how many in a row you need to win:  ");
      // need = kbd.nextInt();
      // System.out.println();

      // TODO: For test purposes only. Delete in running code
      size = 3;
      need = 3;
      names[0] = "Foo";
      names[1] = "Bar";

      game = new TicTacToeGame(size, need, names);

      while (!game.haveWinner() && !game.isFull()) {
         player = (player + 1) % 2;
         try {
            game.playOneTurn(player);
         } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
         }
         System.out.println("While loop looped");
      }

      if (game.haveWinner())
         System.out.println(names[player] + " is the winner!");
      else
         System.out.println("It's a TIE!");

      System.out.println("\nBye!");

   }
}

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
class TicTacToeGame extends JPanel {
   private static final Object LOCK = new Object();
   private volatile int player = 0;
   private int size;
   private int need;
   private String[] names;
   private JLabel nameLabel = new JLabel();
   // private JButton testButton = new JButton();
   private JButton[][] buttonGrid;
   private volatile boolean waiting = false;

   public TicTacToeGame(int size, int need, String[] names) {
      this.size = size;
      this.need = need;
      this.names = names;

      nameLabel.setText(names[0]);

      JPanel topPanel = new JPanel();
      topPanel.add(new JLabel("Player:"));
      topPanel.add(nameLabel);

      buttonGrid = new JButton[size][size];
      ButtonListener actionListener = new ButtonListener(this);
      JPanel middlePanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(size, size));
      for (int row = 0; row < size; row++) {
         for (int col = 0; col < size; col++) {
            JButton button = new JButton("   ");
            middlePanel.add(button);
            buttonGrid[row][col] = button;
            button.addActionListener(actionListener);
         }
      }

      setLayout(new BorderLayout());
      add(topPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
      add(middlePanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

      // run GUI on Swing event thread
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.getContentPane().add(TicTacToeGame.this);
            frame.pack();
            frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            frame.setVisible(true);
         }
      });
   }

   public int getPlayer() {
      return player;
   }

   public synchronized void playOneTurn(final int player)
         throws InterruptedException {
      this.player = player;
      System.out.printf("Player %d before wait%n", player);
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            nameLabel.setText(names[player]);
         }
      });
      synchronized (LOCK) {
         waiting = true;
         while (waiting) {
            LOCK.wait();
         }
      }
   }

   public boolean isFull() {
      for (int row = 0; row < size; row++) {
         for (int col = 0; col < size; col++) {
            if (buttonGrid[row][col].isEnabled()) {
               return false;
            }
         }
      }
      return true;
   }

   public boolean haveWinner() {
      // TODO finish this
      return false;
   }

   public void doNotification() {
      new Thread(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            synchronized (LOCK) {
               waiting = false;
               LOCK.notifyAll();
            }
         }
      }).start();
   }

   public void tttButtonPressed(ActionEvent e) {
      AbstractButton source = (AbstractButton) e.getSource();
      for (int r = 0; r < size; r++) {
         for (int c = 0; c < size; c++) {
            if (buttonGrid[r][c] == source) {
               String text = player == 0 ? "X" : "0";
               source.setText(text);
               source.setEnabled(false);
            }
         }
      }
      doNotification();
   }

}

class ButtonListener implements ActionListener {
   private TicTacToeGame ticTacToeGame;

   public ButtonListener(TicTacToeGame ticTacToeGame) {
      this.ticTacToeGame = ticTacToeGame;
   }

   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
      ticTacToeGame.tttButtonPressed(e);
   };
}
```

Comment: That part of the code, everything in the "App" (if you look at the Dropbox link), was provided by my teacher. I was not suppose to edit it, I was suppose to make the "GameClass". How is that `while` not event driven, I may be missing a basic idea here.

Comment: @ChrisWilson4: are you sure that your game is supposed to be a Swing GUI? It looks to me like you need to create a simple console program, and that's it.

Comment: @EelsHovercraft: Yeah, teach had us make a console game, then using the same app make it a GUI. I turned it in already and had to go see him when he gave me the 70%. He ran it on his desktop and it worked exactly right, keeps executing the whole program so he gave me the 100%.

Comment: @ChrisWilson4: No, I'm wrong, you will need some sort of way to do this that meshes console program with Swing. If your teacher really assigned this, he/she is messed up.

Comment: He is a great teacher, really popular with the guys who are actually good programmers. It is his first semester teaching this course though so maybe some things were rushed. If I'm having this issue because of the way the "app" is behaving, what sorts of changes should be made?

Comment: OK, that is the conclusion I was coming toward slowly. That the `ActionListener` should be in charge.

Comment: @ChrisWilson4: please see edit to answer. I am trying to take care that Swing code is called on the Swing event thread, and that waiting and synchronization is done on non-Swing threads.

Comment: Thanks for the long edit. I will def focus on making sure the assignment I'm on now is event driven. I tried implementing the synchronization like you posted and it work sorta but needs the kinks worked out, of which I'll have to get back. Thanks for helping me with this.

Comment: @ChrisWilson4: you're welcome. It's a most interesting problem. Thanks for sharing it with us!

Answer (score 2):

Oh OK, I found the bug.

```
public class TicTacToeGame extends JFrame {
    public synchronized void playOneTurn(int player)
            throws InterruptedException {
        wait();
    }

    class ButtonListener implements ActionListener {
        @Override
        public synchronized void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            notifyAll();
        }
    }
}
```

I reduced the code so it's more obvious. `playOneTurn` is synchronized and waits on the `TicTacToeGame` instance but `actionPerformed` is synchronized and notifies on the `ButtonListener` instance.

A fix would be something like this (since `ButtonListener` is an inner class):

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    synchronized (TicTacToeGame.this) {
        TicTacToeGame.this.notifyAll();
    }
}
```

Or create a separate object just to be a monitor.

But as I said before (and @HovercraftFullOfEels also seems to be saying), you could do to simply remove the while loop from the program and just use the event as a single entry point.

Also: don't forget to [create your GUI on the EDT with invokeLater](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html).

Comment: 1+ -- I like this better than my answer.

Answer (score 0):

When code of the ActionListner more time consuming in execution, it halts all other part of the program from running.

So, create a new thread when the control enters the ActionListner. so it leverage the main thread to run other code while the thread you created runs your ActionListner part of the code.

Example:

```
    void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    Thread t = new Thread(new runnable()) {

        public void run() {

            System.out.println("Entering Action Performed");

            for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {

                for (j = 0; j < size; j++) {

                    if (e.getSource() == cells[i][j]) {

                        if (model[i][j] == 'e') {

                            cells[i][j].setText("");

                            currentSpot[0] = i;

                            currentSpot[1] = j;

                            if (count % 2 == 0) {

                                cells[i][j].setBackground(Color.GREEN);

                                cells[i][j].setIcon(X_MARK);

                                model[i][j] = 'x';

                                count++;

                                waiting = false;
                                System.out.println("Boolean hit");

                                notifyAll();

                            } else {

                                cells[i][j].setBackground(Color.CYAN);

                                cells[i][j].setIcon(O_MARK);

                                model[i][j] = 'o';

                                count++;

                                waiting = false;

                                System.out.println("Boolean hit");

                                notifyAll();

                            }

                        } else {
                            System.out
                                    .println("Hey, you can't move there silly!");

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    };// runnable ends here

}
```